# Retrieve Governance Actions from MCAS policy

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am using below api to get MCAS policy details like Policy name.

```
Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri "https://xxx.yyyy.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/cas/api/v1/policies/" -Headers @{Authorization = "Token XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"} -Method GET  -Verbose
```

I am looking for a code to pull the Governance Action details specified for the policy using API

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call Microsoft Cloud App Security API with PowerShell, please refer to the following steps

1. Generate API token

   a. Login  [Cloud App Security portal](https://portal.cloudappsecurity.com/)

   b. On the **Settings menu**, select **Security extensions** and then **API tokens**
   [image]

   c. Click the **plus** icon, **Generate new toke**n and provide a name to identify the token in the future, and click **Next**.
   [image]
   [image]

   d. Copy Token and URL
   [image]
2. Call the api

```
$token="<the api token you copy>"
$baseUrl="https://xxx.xxx.portal.cloudappsecurity.com"
$url="$($baseUrl)/cas/api/v1/policies/"

$response=Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Token $($token)"} -Method GET  -Verbose
$response = $response.data
$response |Format-Table -Property  name,matchesCount -AutoSize
```

[image]